# Hive query to find the ip address and country which is not present

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table named 'Login'. It contains the following columns :-

```
UserID | UserName | UserIP | UserCountry | Date
```

On a particular day (all that logins of that day), I want to find out the UserIDs, which has been accessed from a country (UserCountry) from where the user has never accessed his account from OR the IPs (UserIP) from which the account has never been accessed before.

Comment: Are you using Hive or MySQL?  These are different databases.

Comment: I am looking for a query for either of them. I believe the query wont be very different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, It turns out, "except" clause is not present in hive. Hence, yes I am looking for a hive query.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with an except where I remove prior countries and IPs

```
select userid, usercountry, userip
from table
where date=xx
except 
select userid, usercountry, userip
from table 
where date<xx
```

Comment: How will you do without using "except". EXCEPT clause is not present in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is the GROUP clause!
You say "has never been accessed before", means COUNT = 1.

To find the IP use only once :

```
select UserId, UserIP, COUNT(UserIP) FROM Login WHERE Date = yourdate GROUP BY UserIP, UserId HAVING COUNT(UserIP) = 1
```

To find the country use only once :

```
select UserId, UserCountry, COUNT(UserCountry) FROM Login WHERE Date = yourdate GROUP BY UserCountry, UserId HAVING COUNT(UserCountry) = 1
```

Comment: The where clause will filter out all the rows with Date < 'your date'. Hence we will end up working on a dataset only from 'your date'

Answer (score 0):

`Left Outer Join` will be able to satisfy your requirement in `HIVE`.

```
select t1.userid, t1.usercountry, t1.userip
from table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
from table t2
ON (t1.userid=t2.userid) 
WHERE t1.date=xx and
t2.data < xx and
(t2.usercountry IS NULL or
t2.userip IS NULL);
```

Hope this helps...